# Circular Reference p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m in Joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query which is:

```
 Select convert(varchar,dateadd(mi,tz.offset,cal.caldate),101) as caldate,
           s.[off],
           s.aban,
           s.ans,
           case when s.[off]  - s.abn_in = 0 then 0 else 1 end as sla,
           g.slgo
          from calend cal left join 
               summ s on cal.caldate = dateadd(mi,tz.offset,s.arrdate)
               inner join gol g on g.id = cal.id
               left outer join zone tz on 
               tz.id = s.arrdate
```

Output:

```
caldate       off     aban     ans     sla     slgo

04/01/2011    1       0        1       1       60
04/01/2011    2       0        2       1       30
03/12/2011    3       1        2       1       90
```

When I run this query I get errors. The problem I see is the tables zone and summ are dependent on each other. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you add a few rows of example data and desired results?

Comment: @Martin I have added some rows of my output

Comment: Off is a keyword and thus should be in brackets

Comment: @ The multi-part identifier "tz.offset" could not be bound

Comment: What exactly is it you wanna achieve with this query? (On a conceptual level) What is the desired output and how does the actual output differ? What you mean by 'The problem i See is the tables zone and summ are dependent on each other'. How are they dependent and how is it a problem? (I see you join them, is that the dependency you mean?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me say that I don't know what you're doing in this query, so my answer might not be the solution you're looking for.  However, if the only issue you're having is the join order, why not start with zone tz, and then join to summ s in this case?

```
select 
    convert(varchar,dateadd(mi,tz.offset,cal.caldate),101) as caldate,
    s.[off],
    s.aban,
    s.ans,
    case when s.[off]  - s.abn_in = 0 then 0 else 1 end as sla,
    g.slgo
from 
    calend cal 
    cross join zone tz 
    left join summ s on cal.caldate = dateadd(mi,tz.offset,s.arrdate) and tz.id = s.arrdate
    inner join gol g on g.id = cal.id
```

It's no longer left join to zone... but was that essential?

Comment: Yes Left Join to Zone is important